# WCF Service throwing a timeout error when using WcfTestClient

Tags: wcf, web-config, wcftestclient

If I send parameters which will cause a lot of data to be pulled I get the following error:

**The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:01:00. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.**

I have increased all of my timeouts. Is there something I have to do on the client side? I am wondering if this is because I am using wcftestclient? Do I need to adjust the operationTimeout?

My webconfig has the following:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Basic" sendTimeout="12:00:00" receiveTimeout="12:00:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="8192"/>          
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="CaseStudyBehavior" name="EDTFS.ADMS.CaseStudyService">        
        <endpoint address="" 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="Basic"                    
                  name="Basic"                    
                  contract="EDTFS.ADMS.ICaseStudyService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  name="Metadata"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CaseStudyBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="24:00:00"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="100"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the WCF Test Client you will find a node called `Config File` beneath your service. Right-click this and select `Edit with SvcConfigEditor` to increase timeout on the client.

Comment: This works but I have to do it every single time I run my service locally. Is there a way to make it stay permanently?

Comment: Select _Tools_ -> _Options..._ in the WCF Test Client menu and uncheck _Always Regenerate Config When Launching Services_.